# Android wait till async task has finished to do specific method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have been searching for the answer but no one really answers because there is no point using async task for that. In Android API 11 or above it will force to code it you do network requests on the main thread so I have to do async task. So, here is the question: Is it possible to wait untill the async task is finished then continue? Because I need the data to be there for the calling method etc.

Here is my code:

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
        new loadURL().execute();



        // Do this when ASYNC HAS FINISHED 
        return jObj;



    }

    class loadURL extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            //do stuff in background 

            return (null);
        }

    }   
}
```

Any questions to answer just leave a comment. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Add an indeterminate progress bar to your layout (blocking your content) or show a loading dialog until onPostExecute() is called on your async task. If you try to block the main thread for the duration of that network request, android will give you an ANR and your users will be upset.

Answer (score 6):

yes you use the `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask` to do whatever you want to do after. That method gets called after the `doInBackground` is finished

Comment: but if im returning something (its a method in another class) i cant return it from the onPostExecute...

Comment: Don't return it then. Take the code that you would've run with the returned value and move it to onpostexecute

Comment: what are you trying to return?

Comment: i need it to return to a different class.. after it calls the method, it would need to do something with the returned data

Comment: So create a callback to the class you want to send whatever to when the task is done

Comment: @DrDebug: You cannot do what you want. The "something with the returned data" needs to be triggered by `onPostExecute()`. You cannot hide an `AsyncTask` inside of a method like this *and* have that method return a value. A typical approach here is to have `getJSONFromUrl()` take some sort of callback as a parameter, where the callback will handle the result processing. Of course, in this case, even easier would be for you to replace all of this with [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or another HTTP wrapper library.

Answer (score 0):

If the operation won't take long (less than a few seconds) you can use the progress bar to keep from allowing the user to do anything. Set something like this in your `AsyncTask`

```
ProgressDialog progress = ProgressDialog.show(LoginScreen.this, "Downloading Users", "Please wait while users are downloaded");

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.isIndeterminate();
        progress.show();
    }
```

You will still want to call your method from `onPostExecute()` as this will just keep the user from being able to do anything but it won't keep any code from running that is in the method you calling the `AsyncTask` from

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()` methods of `object`s. Or You can use custom callbacks via `interface`s. Just call proper method via callback when you complete getting required data.

Answer (score -1):

You can perform Network related operation inside **doInBackground()** method because **onPostExecute()** method is used only for UI updation only in android